# Hide smoke domain objects in OpenGL quick render

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to hide the domain object for a smoke simulation in an openGL quick render without hiding the smoke?
The domain can be distracting in preview renders even when rendered as a wireframe.
Toggling the visibility of the domain hides the smoke as well.

Is this possible?

Comment: Using the "Only Render" checkbox in the Display panel of the 3D View's Properties region (N) doesn't work?

Comment: @Fweeb Nope. *Only Render* only hides things like the 3D cursor, the grid floor, etc. It does not seem to hide actual geometry.

Comment: If the geometry is set to have a maximum drawtype of Wire, it shouldn't show up when Only Render is enabled.

Comment: @Fweeb Ah, I know why I was confused now.. enabling *Adaptive Domain* makes the domain visible again. Is there a way to hide the domain with *Adaptive domain* enabled? (or maybe this is a bug?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your domain's *Maximum Draw Type* is set to *Wire* (Object Properties > Display panel), you can set the 3D View's display to *Only Render* (Properties region [<kbd>N</kbd>] > Display panel) and the domain should be hidden from view.